# DOJO - Query XmlStore using XPath

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, dojo

I have a **dojox.data.XmlStore** and I want to query the xml store using XPath. Is there a way to do so ?
The example below represent a query for an attribute, but I want to use XPath query provided by item element.

```
var store = new dojox.data.XmlStore({url: "books.xml", rootItem: "book"});
var gotBooks = function(items, request){
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var item = items[i];
    console.log("Located book: " + store.getValue(item, "title");
  }
}
var request = store.fetch({query: {isbn:"A9B57*"}, onComplete: gotBooks});
```

For example if I have a dojo **dijit.Tree** element, it support **onClick** event, I want to be able to fetch the content of the selected element. The item element has a field called "query" that represent the XPath query for the item itself.
How can I use this XPath query to fecth data from store ?

```
var tree = new Tree({
    model: myModel,
    onClick: function(item){
        //the item parameter has a field called "query" that represent the XPath query for the item itself.
    }
});
```

If I'm using the "query" field from **XmlItem** no result is provided. `var request = store.fetch({query: item.q , onComplete: gotBooks});`.

Answer (score 0):

Try use regExp instead of "*" in your query, like:

```
var request = store.fetch({query: {isbn:new RegExp('A9B57','i')}, onComplete: gotBooks});
```

If you need query all, just use:

```
var request = store.fetch({query: {}, onComplete: gotBooks});
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract data from **XmlStore** we can use the filed **query** provided by **XmlItem**, like in the example below.

Answer was found in **Dojo** sources in **dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel#getChildren()**

```
store.fetch({
          //for the query element the item.query field can be used in this way
           query: item.query, 
           onComplete: onComplete,
           onError: onError
});
```